# CSRF token not found, unless using incognito browser

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

Something is wrong with how my Spring web app handles CSRF tokens. When I try to login in browser, I get the following error:

`There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.`

Strangely, **the error goes away if I use incognito mode in Chrome or another machine**. So I figured maybe I'm stuck with an outdated CSRF cookie, and I deleted the only cookie associated with the login page in Chrome. When I refresh, I can see that the server provided me with a fresh cookie that is different from the original one. How is it possible that the error still persists?

I was able to reproduce the issue on another machine earlier and when I deleted everything in Chrome, it started working. I don't want to delete everything from Chrome on this machine, and also, I would like to understand what caused the issue in the first place.

I can see the following field in both Incognito mode and normal:

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="96dddccc-4425-40b2-9947-462877c94238">`

However, when I refresh the page in normal mode, I get a new CSRF value every time, whereas when I refresh the page in incognito mode, I get the same value every time.

I went through all the configs in my Spring app and I haven't configured CSRF tokens anywhere. Spring is doing that inside some black box that I can't access to see what's wrong.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue (on this machine) by deleting cookies in a different manner than earlier. Earlier I tried deleting cookies by clicking next to the address bar, where it showed only 1 cookie (`JSESSIONID`). When I deleted cookies from Chrome Settings window instead, it showed 2 cookies: `JSESSIONID` and a `remember-me` cookie. After deleting both it started working. Not sure if the issue was the remember-me cookie or having the page open while deleting cookies via address bar.